# POST a file attachment in POSTMAN to API

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, crm, google-chrome-app, postman

I am having trouble POSTING a file attachment to Insightly API through Postman

201 Status code with all other fields except file attachment.
See screenshots.
Docs: Send a note file attachment https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Help/Api/POST-Notes_c_id_filename
Tells me I need the Note ID but it automatically assigns it as you see in the first screenshot?

Do I need to post file as a special format/encrypt/content-type rather than the url string? or another process?

**POST**

### [image: POST]

**GET (this is manually entered/uploaded through CRM to show you response  key/value)**

[image: GET]

I have tried the 'form-data' option as well with no luck - key field like this:

[FILE_ATTACHMENT][URL] & value field as file format.
 [FILE_ATTACHMENT][FILE_NAME] & value field as text format.

&

FILE_ATTACHMENT[0].URL & value field as file format.
 FILE_ATTACHMENT[0].FILE_NAME & value field as text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have solved my problem.

The url was incorrect and needed params like this https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Notes/?c_id=1234567&filename=filename.pdf based on Insightly's API.

I used form-data body with the content-type header needed as`multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`